# Add text if class

Tags: jquery

The code below turns a link menu into a drop-down menu with `<option></option>`.

The main categories of the menu have class `category`. sub-categories of the menu have class `sub-category`. I would like to add the `-` character to the sub-categories to obtain a menu structured as follows:

```
category
- sub-category
- sub-category
- sub-category

category

category

- sub-category
```

How can I do this?

```js
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery("#cat-navi").append("<select/>");
  jQuery("#cat-navi select").addClass("form-control");
  jQuery("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value": "",
    "text": "Select Product"
  }).appendTo("#cat-navi select");
  
  //new dropdown menu
  jQuery("#cat-navi a").each(function() {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var perfix = '';
    switch (el.parents().length) {
      case (11):
        perfix = '-';
        break;
      case (13):
        perfix = '--';
        break;
      default:
        perfix = '';
        break;
    }
    
    jQuery("<option />", {
      "value": el.attr("href"),
      "text": perfix + el.text()
    }).appendTo("#cat-navi select");
  });

  jQuery('#cat-navi select').change(function() {
    window.location.href = this.value;
  });
});
```

Output HTML:

```
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0">
            <ul id="cat-navi" class="nav nav-list">
            <a href='index.php?idcati=45&category=smartphones'><li class='category'><strong>SMARTPHONES</strong></li></a>
            <li style='padding:0'><a  style='padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0' href='./index.php?idscat=170&subcategory=apple'  style='font-size:14px'>Apple</a></li>
            <li style='padding:0'><a  style='padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0' href='./index.php?idscat=172&subcategory=huawei'  style='font-size:14px'>Huawei</a></li>
            <li style='padding:0'><a  style='padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0' href='./index.php?idscat=174&subcategory=samsung'  style='font-size:14px'>Samsung</a></li>
        </div>
```

PHP link

```
echo "<li style='padding:0'><a  style='padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0' href='./index.php?idscat=$idscat&subcategory=$subcategory'  style='font-size:14px'>$subcategory</a></li>";
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so that we can see this code actually working in order to understand how best to achieve your goal

Comment: My HTML is generate dynamically:


echo "<li style='padding:0'><a  style='padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0' href='./index.php?idscat=$idscat&subcategory=$subcategory'  style='font-size:14px'>$subcategory</a></li>";

I don't know how to change JQuery and HTML.

Comment: In that case copy the output of the PHP in to the question.

Comment: I have update my question with the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you advise me how to proceed with respect to the code I updated above?

Answer (score -2):

This might work:

```
$(".sub-category").prepend(document.createTextNode(" - "));
```